# How to retrieve distinct values with JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

How can you get distinct values from a SharePoint List column using JavaScript without a huge performance hit?

A simple example would be appreciated :)

Comment: How many items you suppose to query? (maximum count)

Comment: Whats the field type - is it a Choice/MultiChoice (and do you allow 'fill in' values) or something else?

Comment: At the moment I'm looking at 100+ items, but that could get a lot more over time id recon. In some lists I have choice fields Ryan, other there is People Picker fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your field is a Choice/MultiChoice field without "Fill In Choices" enabled then you can use get_choices.

If it does have fill in choices and/or is a different field type then I don't think there is an option apart from brute force (iter over all items getting unique values).

http://spdailytips.blogspot.com/2011/11/retrieve-all-choice-field-values-using.html

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">

function GetChoiceValues() {
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
  var web = context.get_web();    
  context.load();

  // Get the list
  var taskList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("list");

  // Get Department choice field (choice field)
  var deptChoiceField = 
      context.castTo(taskList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("department"),
                     SP.FieldChoice);

  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
                            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod)); 
}

function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
    var choices = deptChoiceField.get_choices();
    listBoxControl1.Items.Add(choices);
    alert("Choices: (" + choices.length + ") - " + choices.join(", "));
}

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
    alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer /_vti_bin/listdata.svc. For example to retrieve only Title och Status from 100 first Tasks:

```
http://dev/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks()?$select=Title, StatusValue&top=100
```

See more on my blog: [$select](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/select-in-listdata-svc/), [$.getJSON and listdata.svc](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/getjson-jquery-tmpl-and-_vti_bin/), [updating with listdata.svc](http://sharepointkunskap.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/update-list-items-with-listdata-svc/)

Comment: i wanna get duplicate list items from the splist, in my SPO, how to retrieve those duplicates?, please help

Answer (score 1):

I've written this function which will get unique values for a column in SharePoint Online, without having to iterate through each item.

```
function getUniqueColumnValues(listid, viewid, column,  _callback){
var uniqueVals = [];
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/filter.aspx?ListId={" + listid + "}&FieldInternalName=" + column + "&ViewId={" + viewid + "}&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    }).then(function(response) {
        $(response).find('OPTION').each(function(a,b){
            if ($(b)[0].value) {
                uniqueVals.push($(b)[0].value);
            }
        });
        _callback(true,uniqueVals);
},function(){
    _callback(false,"Error retrieving unique column values");
});
```

}