# Distinct values of SPFieldUserValue List

Tags: 2010, list, visual-studio

I'm working with visual studio 2010 and I have this list:

```
    List<SPFieldUserValue> directeursDelegues = (from SPListItem agence in webSite.Lists[agenceGuid].Items
                                         select (SPFieldUserValue)delegueField.GetFieldValue(agence["Directeur_x0020_D_x00e9_l_x00e9_"].ToString())
                                         ).Distinct().ToList();
```

I'm trying to get distinct values from this list. But it doesn't seem to work.
Do you know how to do it?

EDIT:

I've found the answer:

```
    List<SPFieldUserValue> directeursDelegues = (from SPListItem agence in webSite.Lists[agenceGuid].Items//agence list
                                                                             select (SPFieldUserValue)delegueField.GetFieldValue(agence["Directeur_x0020_D_x00e9_l_x00e9_"].ToString())
                                                                             ).GroupBy(x => x.User.ID).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
```

I don't know if it is the best way but it works fine.

Comment: If its working fine, go for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CAML query schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx) for Sharepoint doesn't contain distinct still, so there is not Distinct operation in CAML Queries.

However you may group results in CAML (using GroupBy element) - it will produce groups for distinct values of the field by which you will perform grouping. So this is only otption for you to get uniques values.

[CAML query on Sharepoint List without duplicates](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77988/caml-query-on-sharepoint-list-without-duplicates)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c2bbcf13-a53d-4755-87dd-871a51840a4d/select-distinct-in-caml-query-for-list